# D3 V4 - Using merge with general update pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was able to successfully use the enter/update/exit logic to update my visualization, however, I'm doing so without using the new `.merge()` function outlined here: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection so something makes me think I'm still doing it the v3 way.  Whenever I try to use the `.merge()` function based on the documentation, it always breaks it.

**I'm hoping you guys can help me figure out how to update the logic and do it the v4 way.**

For example, in the following code I join the data to `<g>` elements and then nest other elements (`<path>` and `<text>`) inside of the `<g>` elements.  So for each block of code where I append data to `vis.group` I need to write an identical block of code which calls the `dataJoin` for the update.

```
// DATA JOIN
var dataJoin = vis.clipPath.selectAll(".group")
  .data(vis.displayData);

// ENTER
vis.group = dataJoin.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "group")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(0," + vis.y(d.registrationEndDate) + ")";
  });

// UPDATE
dataJoin
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(0," + vis.y(d.registrationEndDate) + ")";
  });

// ENTER
var path = vis.group.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .style("opacity", 0.1)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.type === "currentEmployments") {
      return "#50A2DA";
    }
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return addPath(d, vis);
  });

// UPDATE
dataJoin.select(".line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return addPath(d, vis);
  });

...
```

All of it seems way too repetitive, and I thought v4 was supposed to fix that by allowing me to use `.merge()`, but when I try something like the below, it doesn't work:

```
// ENTER
var path = vis.group.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .style("opacity", 0.1)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.type === "currentEmployments") {
      return "#50A2DA";
    }
  })
  .merge(dataJoin) // ENTER + UPDATE
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return addPath(d, vis);
    });
```

I'm expecting to be able to combine the separate enter and update blocks into one combined enter + update block with merge.  Am I wrong on the logic here?

**FULL EXAMPLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bschxdjb/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, just the selection passed to the merge function is incorrect. Check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g791bkwL/):

```
  // ENTER
  vis.group = dataJoin.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group");

  // UPDATE
  vis.group
    .merge(dataJoin)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(0," + vis.y(d.registrationEndDate) + ")";
    });

  // ENTER
  var path = vis.group.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("opacity", 0.1)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.type === "currentEmployments") {
        return "#50A2DA";
      }
    })
    .merge(dataJoin.select(".line"))
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return addPath(d, vis);
    });


  // Append Firm Name
  vis.group.append("text")
    .attr("class", "firm-name")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if (d.type === "currentEmployments") {
        return "#50A2DA";
      }
    })
    .merge(dataJoin.select(".firm-name"))
    .text(function(d) {
      var label = d.name;
      return label;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      var range = vis.y(d.registrationBeginDate) - vis.y(d.registrationEndDate);
      return "translate(50," + (range / 2) + ")";
    });


  // Append Year range
  vis.group.append("text")
    .attr("class", "years")
    .attr("fill", "#696969")
    .merge(dataJoin.select(".years"))
    .text(function(d) {
      var count = d3.timeYear.count(d.registrationBeginDate, d.registrationEndDate);
      var years = '';
      if (count > 1) {
        years = " (" + count + " years)";
      } else if (count == 1) {
        years = " (" + count + " year)";
      } else if (count < 1) {
        years = " (<1 year)";
      }
      var label = convertToYear(d.registrationBeginDate) + " - " + convertToYear(d.registrationEndDate) + years;
      return label;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      var range = vis.y(d.registrationBeginDate) - vis.y(d.registrationEndDate);
      return "translate(50," + ((range / 2) + 15) + ")";
    });
```

Comment: Perfect! You are right in that `.select("[class]")` is what was missing from my `.merge()` calls.